# Optimize code to search for multiple keywords in word document

Tags: powershell

Below code works perfectly fine, and extract the required sections from word document. We have to search for nearly 50 keywords one by one in document, how can we optimize this code. Because with currently approach we search for one keyword, then open document again and search again. This is taking very long in execution time. Any suggestions.

BELOW code: Extract text between two HEADINGS, how to optimize this so that we can it make it work to search for 50 keywords... opening document once and scanning till end..

```
function ExtractSectionsFromWordDoc{
Param([string]$SourceFile, [string]$Category, [string]$SearchKeyword1, [string]$SearchKeyword2, [string]$TableName)

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($SourceFile,$false,$true)
$sel = $word.Selection 
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs 

foreach ($para in $paras) 
{ 
    $style = $para.Style 
    If ($style.NameLocal -eq "Heading 2") 
    { 

        if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword1)
        {
            $startPosition = $para.Range.Start
            Write-Host $startPosition
        }
        if ($para.Range.Text -match $SearchKeyword2)
        {
            $endPosition = $para.Range.Start
            Write-Host $endPosition
            break
        }
    }
} 
[array]$content=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$content=$doc.Range($startPosition, $endPosition).text
$content = $content -replace "'", ""

# cleanup com objects
$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

Comment: Do the search terms/keywords always come in pairs?

Comment: we use pairs, because thats help to define range... by using first keyword we get start point and by using second keyword we get end point

Comment: how can we modify this code so that we can get some performance... because opening/scanning document for 50 keywords is too process intensive and takes longer

Comment: Your code only allows to a single string entry for each keyword, thus the need to restart. You should tweak this to accept an array for each of the keywords, of tweak this to use a file to pass in the keywords and loop thru that file via the single word docx.